How can I upload a CSV file from a local folder to a specific folder within an S3 bucket using Python?
If I have a CSV file stored in a specific local folder, how can I upload it to a specific folder within an S3 bucket using Python?

import boto3
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M")
local_path = '/root/my_folder/'
filename = f'file_{timestamp}.csv'
df.to_csv(f{local_path}{filename}', index=False)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'bucket'
folder_name = 'output'
object_name = f'{folder_name}/{filename}'

s3.upload_file(f'{local_path}{filename}', bucket_name, object_name)

